# AHK: Script Help Num Lock acting up

Tags: autohotkey

Hello I am trying to make a script for autohotkey and I am getting some weird stuff happening when I use the Numpad2 hotkey I made.

The first 2 presses work perfectly fine, it toggles on and runs the script until I press Numpad2 again then it toggles off.

When I press Numpad2 for the 3rd time though, it starts to act up. It wont turn off again and acts like the Num Lock key was pressed and turned off.

So instead of getting 2 when I press Numpad2 I get the down key.

It also seems like it's holding down the shift button.

I can't figure out why this keeps happening, looking at this script there is no Num Lock key presses anywhere, why would it be doing this?

```
Numpad2::
Send, {Numpad1}
autominestop += 1
if autominestop > 1
{
  SetTimer, RTimer, off
  autominestop = 0
  Send, {LButton up}
  Send, {RButton up}
;  TrayTip, Auto-mine is OFF, Auto-mine is OFF`npress NUMPAD2 to turn if ON., 8, 17    ;Debug Info
  Return
}
else
{
  SetTimer, RTimer, 99000
  Send, {LButton down}
  Send, {RButton down}
;  TrayTip, Auto-mine is ON, Auto-mine is ON`npress NUMPAD2 to turn if OFF., 8, 17     ;Debug Info
}
Return

RTimer:
Send, {R}
Return





Numpad1::
tspammerstop += 1
if tspammerstop > 1
{
  SetTimer, TTimer, off
  tspammerstop = 0
}
else
{
  SetTimer, TTimer, 50
}

TTimer:
Send, {T}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I feel like an idiot for posting this. I was using uppercase T instead of lowercase, so AHK was pressing shift which uses the arrow keys instead of the numbers on the numberpad.